# Allocate pools of hugepages separately on each NUMA doamin

Tags: linux, memory, numa, huge-pages

On my dual-socket machine, I'm trying to allocated two pools of hugepages (one for each socket), so that the application A, which is pinned on the first socket, uses the first pool, and the application B on the second socket uses it's own local pool.

However, when I put the number of huge pages in the `/sys/devices/system/node/node{0,1}/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages`, the `hugeadm --explain` still shows me a single pool and one mount point for it, instead of two.

The goal is to have two processes one on each socket, so that each process works only on the local pool of hugepages.